# T-SQL statement to add column values if the have same overview ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am very new to SQL Server so I need all the help I can get. I wanted write a query that runs against a table.

Here is the requirement.

The table has this kind of data

```
projID         ALLW           OBLIG   
-----------------------------------------
459OU2002       2637368.14      637368.14   
459OU2002A     23448321.33    12853209.88
459OU2002B     12853209.88    23448321.33
```

The result I want is:

```
projID         ALLW                OBLIG    
------------------------------------------------------------------------
459OU2002       38938888.47(sum of all 3)     369388900.35(sum of all 3)
```

THE PROJECT ID HAS PHASE. A AND B. IF THE PROJECT ID HAVE A PHASE ALL THE COST UNDER IT HAVE TO BE ROLLED UP (ADD UP) UNDER OVER VIEW. For example if project Id 101AU212 has ALLW 50.00 and has a phase under project ID 101AU212A and ALLW is 100.00. I want the project Id 101AU212 displaying 150.00 ALLW.

Thanks

Comment: Don't shout while asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see below code if you are using SQL SERVER 2005 and above..

```
DECLARE @Input TABLE
(ProjID VARCHAR(20),
Allw DECIMAL(15,2),
Oblig DECIMAL(15,2)
)

INSERT INTO @Input VALUES('459OU2002', 2637368.14, 637368.14), ('459OU2002A', 23448321.33, 12853209.88), ('459OU2002B', 12853209.88, 23448321.33)

;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT LEFT(ProjID,9) AS ProjID, Allw, Oblig 
FROM @Input
)
SELECT ProjID, SUM(Allw) AS Allw, SUM(Oblig) AS Oblig 
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ProjID
```

If you are using SQL 2000, use a subquery instead of CTE.

Comment: thanks it workes. i just changed insert into @input select projID,allw,oblig since i have many data. Thnaks again